# Changing an object from another thread during serialization

Tags: c#, multithreading, serialization

Consider the following object:

```
class MyObject
{
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }
}
```

I want to enable thread-safe serialization in my custom serializer (which can take any type of object) so that it locks MyObject from edits while it's being serialized.  It would subsequently lock `Numbers` and `StringValue` (even though it's immutable already) from edits while they're being serialized.

Is there a way that I can lock any given object so that it can't be accessed/modified by other threads so that my object tree doesn't change while I'm serializing it?  If not, is this considered to not be a problem that the serializer needs to address, but rather one of the user of the serializer?  How do BinarySerializer and XmlSerializer handle this?

**Note:** `lock(){}` doesn't do what I'm looking for.  It only provides a mechanism which prevents other threads from placing a lock on that object; that object may still be edited:

```
class Program
{
    private static List<int> _list;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _list = new List<int>{1,2,3};
        var thread = new Thread(Edit) {IsBackground = true};

        lock (_list)
        {
            _list.Add(4);
            thread.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(20);
            _list.Add(100);
        }
        while (thread.IsAlive) {}
        _list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Edit()
    {
        for (int i = 5; i < 35; i++)
        {
            _list.Add(i);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx)

Comment: @I4V, I don't know if that's a joke or not...

Answer (score 0):

BinarySerializer and XmlSerializer don't handle this at all. If you need something like this, it would be up to you to develop some sort of "contract" between your serializer and your serializable objects. I don't think there's a good way to make this generic for any type of object.

Comment: I thought that, but wasn't sure.  It seems as if they delegate that responsibility to the consumer of the serializer.  I have no problem following that pattern (less for me to do).